# How does this for-loop actually work?

Tags: c++, c

Reading some topics I found this piece of code, and I'm wondering, how does it works, because it prinst:

```
5
2
```

The code:

```
static int a = 7;

int test()
{
  return a--;
}

int main()
{
  for(test();test();test())
  {
    cout << test() << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Funny name, I almost thought it was random.

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth i don't understad how does the for loop work.

Comment: rand() is not rand() afterall. sigh.

Comment: You understand how a for loop in general works right? (The four parts of it, when they get called). Write that out for a "normal" for loop and then this monster and count the executions of `rand()` in relation to the prints.

Comment: Please read this line by line  
initial:  rand()=7  
condition: rand()=6 > 0  
into the first loop  cout << rand() = 5  
iter:  rand()=4
condition:  rand()=3 > 0  
into the second loop  cout << rand() = 2  
iter:  rand()=1  
condition:  rand()=0 <= 0  
so terminate

Comment: @cloudygoose In your last part "rand()=0 <= 0"; it needs to be ==0, not <=0 to terminate.  Likewise where you say "rand()=3 > 0", it should be rand()=3 != 0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Order of operations, as presented:

1. `a` is globally initialized on startup. to 7
2. Initializer of for-loop is hit first, `test()` decrements `a` to 6, then returns the prior value (7), which is ignored.
3. The test case of for-loop is hit, `test()` decrements `a` to 5, then returns the prior value (6) which passes the non-zero test so the for-loop can continue.
4. The `cout` statement; `test()` decrements `a` to 4, returning the prior value **(5)** which is sent to `cout`.
5. The increment-statement of the for-loop is executed. `test()` decrements `a` to 3, returning the prior value (4), which is ignored.
6. The test case of the for-loop is hit. `test()` decrements `a` to 2, returning the prior value (3), which passes the non-zero test and the loop continues.
7. The `cout` statement; `test()` decrements `a` to 1, returning the prior value **(2)** which is sent to `cout`.
8. The increment-statement of the for-loop is executed. `test()` decrements `a` to 0, returning the prior value (1), which is ignored.
9. The test case of the for-loop is hit. `test()` decrements `a` to -1, returning the prior value (0), which fails the non-zero test and the loop terminates.

Now. Start that loop at 6 or 8 and see what happens. =P

Comment: thanks, but why it returns the prior value? is there a rule or something about the static variables?

Comment: @ddacot The post-unary operators (both -- and ++) work that way by design. The statement `x = a++` does two things. (1) increments `a` by one, and (2) returns the *prior* value of `a` as the expression value, which is then assigned to `x`. For some reason instructors teach this completely wrong. They say "`a` is assigned to `x`, then `a` is incremented." While it may *appear* that way, that is not, in fact, the correct order of operations.

Comment: @ddacot Though a separate issue, it merits pointing out, and I'll do so with a *very* simple code sample to prove the order of operations in a post-unary operator if you desire. It is trivial to demonstrate, and worth an occasional zinger to an instructor that thinks they know better. If you want a sample, let me know.

Comment: What is `rand` supposed to be?

Comment: @David I can tell you what it is: A very poorly named function. The function name in the question wasn't really relevant (beyond the laughter and cajoling). Why it worked the way it did in the `for`-loop was the ultimate question. It appears the someone renamed it to `test()`, so I should probably do said-same in my answer.

Answer (score 12):

A `for` loop of the form:

```
for (a; b; c) {
    // stuff
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
{
    a;
    while (b) {
        // stuff
        c;
    }
}
```